# how to detect when i scrolled below the UITableView AND snaps back

Tags: ios, scroll

im atempting to do a facebook type load more data and right now it works, but very laggy on the device because its asking the server to get anything that isnt there already, then calling a scroll all the way down function (because somehow when i reload the data it scrolls to the top). If there would be a way to prevent scrolling to the top that would be great. But my main thing is, is there a way to detect when i scrolled down, and LET GO (stopped scrolling) as in i scrolled past what i have, then it went back to its possition and then calls my methods... Currently it keeps getting called when the scroll is greater then the height of the UITableView heres the code

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;

    if(distanceFromBottom < height)
    {
        [getMessage removeAllObjects];
        [self loadMessages];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self scrollAllTheWayDown];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh). Even if you roll your own, you can see how they're doing it.

Comment: On iOS 6, this is what UIRefreshControl is intended to solve for you.

Comment: @matt i looked at the documentation and im kind of lost, i dont even know where to start with that, can you show me some example code?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_refreshing_table_view_data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

does what you want. it gets called after user stops scrolling, and you can check for scrollOffset at that point to see if you should trigger your refresh code. (you'd use scrollViewDidScroll to update the view to show user update will happen if he lets go)

Comment: try changing your `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;` without any code changes and you should get your refresh when you are expecting it.

Comment: the rest of my comment was that if you want to show an arrow or sth as the user scrolls beyond the end you'd do that in scrollViewDidScroll as you'd want the user to see the arrow appear as he's scrolling, not when he's done.

Comment: Ahh i see. Good idea. I could put a label there that would change from "Pull down" to "Loading..." in that sense correct?